# How to chain functions from array to object in Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I was hoping this work, but it didn't:

```
var myName = _(myArray)
    .find({ "ID": 5 })
    .get("Name");
```

Basically I want to find one element within an array, where ID property is equal to 5 and then get value of "Name" property of that.

What am I missing ?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Are you getting any error message? Can you show some sample data?

Comment: @thefourtheye the error I was getting: `Object does not support 'get' property`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below, I have written three different calls which will all return the desired data. As they say, there is more than one way to skin a cat, when it comes to programming. You must choose the most effective or efficient for your needs.

The two latter function below, which uses the `_.result` function, have been adapted from the lodash documentation. You can use result as a replacement for `_.get()`.

> ### [`_.result(object, path, [defaultValue])`](https://lodash.com/docs#result)
>
> This method is like `_.get` except that if the resolved value is a function it’s invoked with the this binding of its parent object and its result is returned.
>
> #### Arguments
>
> - `object` *(Object)*: The object to query.
> - `path` *(Array*|*string)*: The path of the property to resolve.
> - `[defaultValue]` *(*)*: The value returned if the resolved value is undefined.
>
> #### Returns
>
> - *(*)*: Returns the resolved value.

```js
var myArray = [
  { ID : 0,  Name : 'Foo' },
  { ID : 1,  Name : 'Bar' },
  { ID : 5,  Name : 'Baz' },
  { ID : 10, Name : 'Oof' }
];

// Convienience function to print to the DOM. (Only for debugging)
function print() {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + [].join.call(arguments, ' ') + '</p>';
}

// Find item using chaining with `_.find()` and `_.get()`.
print(
  '<span class="lbl">Chain + Find + Get:</span>',
  _(myArray).chain().find({ 'ID' : 5 }).get('Name')
);

// Find item using a predicate (function).
print(
  '<span class="lbl">Find (Function Predicate) + Result:</span>',
  _.result(_.find(myArray, function(chr) {
    return chr.ID === 5;
  }), 'Name')
);

// Find item using the `_.matches()` callback shorthand.
print(
  '<span class="lbl">Find (Object Predicate) + Result:</span>',
  _.result(_.find(myArray, { 'ID' : 5 }), 'Name')
);
```

```css
.lbl {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `.get()` here. `.find()` returns the matching object, so to pull its `Name` property you can simply reference `.Name` on that object:

```
var myName = _(myArray).find({ "ID": 5 }).Name;
```

This will only work if the `.find()` call succeeds. You may want to store the result of the `.find()` in a variable, then check if that isn't `null` before returning the `Name` property:

```
var match = _(myArray).find({ "ID": 5 }),
    myName;

if (match) {
    myName = match.Name;
}
```

Comment: `get()` can be a good substitute for `if` statements that check for a match, and intermediary variables. For instance, `var myName = _.get(_.find(myArray, { ID: 5 }), 'Name');`.